# 8.6 ohm resistor is decreasing 3.97volts to 2.95 volts which is connected to zener diode i can't understand how it is happening

Tags: resistors, zener, nodemcu

i'm trying to pass 3.3v to nodemcu from a 4v battery, For that I'm using a resistor of 8.6ohms and a zener diode of 3.6v. and the circuit diagram is as follows

[image]
 but when i simulate the circuit in online simulator 8.6ohms resistor is reducing much lower voltage.But in real time it is reducing 10volts nearly. i can't understand where the mistake is.Please answer me and suggest me other ways to power my nodemcu from 3.7-4.2v battery easily and efficiently.

Comment: "But in real time it is reducing 10volts nearly" so you end up with -6V from a 4V battery? Also why don't you just use a standard linear regulator?

Comment: For starters, the current should be the same at every point in that circuit.

Comment: unless that multimeter is taking current?

Comment: sorry I didn't understand what you are saying, is there any problem with my circuit

Comment: There's no reason for a simulated multimeter to draw any current!

Comment: i'm just checking the output with multimeter in simulation

Comment: Cartoon time is here again.

Comment: what??? sorry, I'm new to electronics, If my question is wrong, My apologies!!!!

Comment: Andy means, draw a proper schematic instead of a silly cartoon.

Comment: you're not trying to _power_ the ESP like that are you?

Answer (score 1):

Your simulated volt-meter is drawing a current, the magnitude of which suggests it has a simulated input resistance of 1Megohm.

The zener diode is drawing very little current, only 5uA at 3.97v. That's not consistent with a simulated zener set to 3.6v. Check what you've set its knee voltage to.

You could investigate the zener model by changing your voltage source, and see what current flows. Or get a better simulator. LTspice is the *de facto* hobbyists simulator.